# Cloning BitBucket (Git) repo through eclipse

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket, mercurialeclipse

I have a BitBucket (Git) repository that I want to work on through eclipse. When I search online I find that I need to use mercurialeclipse. So I install it. Then I try doing in eclipse `File > import > mercurial > clone existing mercurial repository`. But when I copy the url from BitBucket, it says `Clone repository URL is invalid!` My guess is that this is happening because my repo is a Git repo. Again, I am very very new to BitBucket so I may be wrong about that.

Can someone please guide to the correct approach? After much failure, I finally found talks about EGit. Should I use that instead? I am using Juno on mac osx mountain lion.

My objective is to be able to do commits etc from within eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried the eclipse git plugin?

Comment: Should I decide to try EGit, must I uninstall the mercurialeclipse plugin first? or may I use both?

Comment: Just try EGit. You can leave the mercurial plugin installed

Comment: @Kata I don't seem to be able to accept your answer where it is. Do you mind rewriting it as an answer?

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the eclipse EGit plugin and use that to clone the Git repository. It is not necessary to uninstall the other plugins (mercurial) in order to work with the eclipse EGit plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Check the user's credentials well, if where you try to clone the repository is a server or ip, check with <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> entering the path of your repository and authenticate so that the eclipse can take the repository correctly.

Comment: Check the user's credentials well, if where you try to clone the repository is a server or ip, check with Windows + R entering the path of your repository and authenticate so that the eclipse can take the repository correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should consider using EGit plugin: the interface is pretty intuitive and the import is easy.